# Solve for $x$: $2\sin^2(x) - \sin^2(2x) = \cos^2(2x)$

Tags: trigonometry

Gonna repeat it in the body for readability, because I don't know if markers work in the title

$2\sin^2(x) - \sin^2(2x) = \cos^2(2x)$

I also put it into Wolfram Alpha and it returned relatively incomprehensible answer involving polynomial transformations, if possible a simpler answer would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Hint: add $\sin^2(2x)$ to both sides

Comment: what happens if you take $\sin^22x$ to the right hand side?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your equation is simply

$$2\sin^2(x) = \underbrace{\cos^2(2x) + \sin^2(2x)}_{=1}$$

Whence

$$\sin^2(x) = \frac{1}{2}$$

Can you proceed from here?

**Solution**

$$\sin(x) = \pm \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$$

This is a well known value and it's $\pi/4$ radians and $3\pi/4$ radians. Since we have $\sin^2$, to be then explicit in the solution we have also $-\pi/4$ and $5\pi/4$ radians:

$$x = \pm \frac{\pi}{4} + 2k\pi ~~~~~~~~~~~ k\in\mathbb{Z}$$
$$x =  \frac{3\pi}{4} + 2k\pi ~~~~~~~~~~~ k\in\mathbb{Z}$$
$$x =  \frac{5\pi}{4} + 2k\pi ~~~~~~~~~~~ k\in\mathbb{Z}$$

Comment: Yes thank you can't believe I missed that

Comment: I believe it also could be simplified to [  x=π/4 + kπ/2  k∈Z  ] or [  x=±π/4 + kπ  k∈Z  ]

Comment: @MaxEast I wanted to make you to see the explicit solutions! :)